# In spring data JPA is there any way to get all column names that get updated in a put rest api?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I want to get all those column names whose values get updated in update query as I am using postgres database and spring data jpa.

Comment: You can do that using Hibernate Interceptor https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#events

Comment: yes ..it's working. thank you